# I can not Install pyscopg2 with sudo yum install django pyscopg2. on centos7

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

Installation will endup with this message.

Command "/usr/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-nbderdof-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-p07ubkfd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-nbderdof-build/
(myprojectenv) [anyuser@localhost myproject]$

Comment: Are you sure that's a full error message?

Comment: Anton Perepelitcyn this line any help                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: It must be something more. Could you, please, show us the whole install output. Put it on pastebin.com for example

Comment: Thank you Anton, and this is the link.
http://pastebin.com/hQPTpWAP

Comment: The error is `./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`.
You have installed `python-devel-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64` but for your app you are using `python-3.4`.
You must install `python-devel-3.4` package or something like that

Comment: "THANK YOU"  Anton, you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install `python-devel` package:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Comment: Package python-devel-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: afirado you close too, however  in my case python3.4 installed as @Anton said with this  package my problem solved: thank you for your effort:          yum install python34-devel